# Asymptotic relation for renewal process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, spatial, convergence, asymptotics

> If we have an ordinary renewal process $X_1, X_2, X_3,\cdots$ in which $X_i$s are the inter-renewal times and the number of renewals in time $t$ is $N(t)$, we have the following relation
>   $$\frac{N(t)}{t}\xrightarrow{a.s}\lambda$$
>   where $\lambda$ is the rate of the renewal process and $\lambda= \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[X_i]}$. Now, assume that $\lambda = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$. How can we prove the following?
>   $$\frac{N(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\xrightarrow{a.s}1$$

My attemp: If we assume $S_n$ is the $n^{th}$ time of arrival, then we know $\frac{N(t)}{S_{N(t)}}<\frac{N(t)}{t}<\frac{N(t)}{S_{N(t)+1}}$. Therefore,

$$\frac{\sqrt{t}N(t)}{S_{N(t)+1}}<\frac{N(t)}{\sqrt{t}}<\frac{\sqrt{t} N(t)}{S_{N(t)}}$$

I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: @whuber   what do you think about it

Comment: If $\lambda$ varies with $t$, then this is no longer a renewal process.